# Error when creating MeteorJS project - can't get arch with uname -p?

Tags: meteor

When I run in my terminal “meteor create new_app”,

I get the following error:

```
d/Users/abc123/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.8.1.4gwv5w.33478++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.browser.legacy+web.cordova/mt-os.osx.x86_64/dev_bundle/lib/node_modules/meteor-promise/promise_server.js:218
throw error;
^

Error: can’t get arch with uname -p?
at run (/tools/utils/archinfo.js:151:15)
at Object.host (/tools/utils/archinfo.js:161:11)
at ProjectContext.reset (/tools/project-context.js:94:45)
at new ProjectContext (/tools/project-context.js:60:8)
at Command.func (/tools/cli/commands.js:769:24)
at /tools/cli/main.js:1531:15
```

It then creates the project folder, but if I cd into the project folder and run “meteor” in the terminal to run the project, nothing runs and I get the an error about there being a missing release file. when I add the release file and re-run, I get the same error posted above.

I have tried reinstalling meteor, and I have it installed using the script from the official website.

Does anybody have any guidance that can help me? Thank you so much!

Comment: Can you please add the permission levels on you meteor installation?